# NativeScript. How do i create a custom action bar with a png image?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm developing a child oriented app with nativescript, i want to make a custom action bar with an image background like this:
[image]

But as you can see, on scroll, it shows a white rectangular background instead of transparent, how can i achieve this, using the Nativescript Layout?

This is what i'm doing:

```html
<GridLayout rows="100,*">
        <app-header row="0"></app-header> //This app header it's the custom component that holds just an image tag with the source.
        
        <ScrollView row="1" orientation="vertical" class="page">
               //Scrolling content...
        </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Have you ensured that your image is a format that supports transparency and that it has transparent areas properly defined?

Comment: I agree with Ian, besides is it iOS / Android? Can you share some code snippet of what you are trying?

Comment: it's android, check the edit

Comment: the image is .png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use color with alpha for ActionBar.If you use opacity proprty for ActionBar, the children will be affected too.
app.css

```
ActionBar{
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
```